# MudPopover remains on the next page of MudCarousel

Tags: mudblazor, mudpopover

I rebuilt the scenario in this sandbox: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GOGnahmylglgFYQN
(Sorry I left here a wrong link before)

In the sandbox, click the > icon on the right side, you should see that the popover "1st page" appears in page1 and page2, and then disappears in page3. So do the "2nd page" and "3rd page". The good news is that they do disappear finally, although a little bit late.

Any idea of how this happened? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The popovers should be detached from the component itself as it's being produced by the `IPopoverService`. So I would think that changing between carousel items shouldn't really toggle the rendering of the the popovers.

I recommend using the `SelectedIndex` to toggle the popover rendering states.

```
<MudCarousel @bind-SelectedIndex="@_selectedIndex" 
    <!-- ... -->
    <MudPopover Open="@(_selectedIndex==0)"
    <!-- ... -->
    </MudPopover>
</MudCarouselItem>

@code{
    private int _selectedIndex;
}
```

[Snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/cOQxYhGzpAXSHHiD)

Comment: Ahh, this is a good idea. I moved to something else rather than MudCarousel. But I think your solution should work great. I will try it later, thanks.